# For a PHP application, how do I set different timeouts for certain URLs in Apache HTTP server?

Tags: php, apache

Is it possible to set up a different timeout for specific URLs. For instance, I would like that `http://myserver.com/save_message` have a timeout of 2 seconds, differently than my server default.

This URL calls a PHP script. Is the PHP script terminated automatically when the timeout happens?

Comment: Question: What's the use of setting the timeout to 2 seconds?

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/tour).

Comment: Hi @CharlotteDunois, this value is just a example. I don't know yet the exact value. I would like to catch this timeout in my PHP script and write it in a log file or table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set timeout by below list different ways:

### (1) In PHP script file (for example, settings.php)

For example you can place this values in common settings file which is being included in all files

ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes

### (2)  .htaccess file settings

php_value max_execution_time 300

### (3) Apache virtual host configuration file settings:

As well if you have access server access than you can set in apache configuration file.
If you do changes in server configuration file than you need to restart apache service.

i.e 

php_value post_max_size 5M
php_value upload_max_filesize 5M
php_value memory_limit 128M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1200

I hope these would be helpful for you.

Comment: Hi @atul... I undestand these ways are possible, but... how can I do It for a specific URL pattern?

Comment: @OmarAlves

.htaccess files are really worth getting to grips with.  They can essentualy be used to redifine the httpd.conf file for single areas of the site.  If you can use them propaly they become exttreamly powerfull tools! 
As each web site Url have their own directory and under particular directory's .htaccess file can do settings like:

php_value max_execution_time 300 

As well you can set for particular file as below:
i.e.
<directory /path/to/file>
  <files yourfilename.php>
  timeout 60
  </files>
</directory>